# Google cloud storage - client secret

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I am totally new to work with google cloud storage. I am trying to upload files to buckets using their tutorials. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/gspythonlibrary
I am not sure where to get "Client Secret" from.
Can someone help me out here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason for you to use the XML API?

The python Storage Client might be a lot easier to use, have a look at the docs:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-python
and
https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/storage-client.html